# How to replace \ with \\ in my response body?

Tags: apex

I am trying to update `\` with `\\` using apex replace getting below error.

```
String response = '{"body":{"statusDesc":"Failure : {\"errorMessages\":[\"leadOwnerId is mandatory\"]}","channelRefId":"","leadRefId":"","leadId":"SF190623017684","statusCode":"FF"},"head":{"statusCd":"100","txnID":"CRMPUSH_20230619123703_25023m"}}';
string res = response.replace('\',\\');
```

Error

```
void replace(String) from the type String
```

Comment: That can't be the entire error message.

Answer (score 0):

Apex knows `\` as an escape character. You need to escape it:

```
String response = '{"body":{"statusDesc":"Failure : {\\"errorMessages\\":[\\"leadOwnerId is mandatory\\"]}","channelR...
```

Comment: still getting System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:37]

Comment: String response = '{"body":{"statusDesc":"Failure : {\"errorMessages\":[\"leadOwnerId is mandatory\"]}","channelRefId":"","leadRefId":"","leadId":"SF190623017684","statusCode":"FF"},"head":{"statusCd":"100","txnID":"CRMPUSH_20230619123703_25023m"}}';
string res = response.replace('\\','\\\\');

Comment: If you hard code the escaped JSON you need to manually escape the escape characters since they are processed by Apex and quietly disappear. On the other hand, if they are received in a real response they are processed in the correct way by the JSON parser. You need to [edit] your question to explain what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: Fundamentally if you use JSON serialisation or deserialization it will automatically handle the escapes for you. On the other hand, you must do it for yourself if you do not. I assumed your example was purely trying to illustrate some issue with data received. If this is literally the code you are trying to use you must escape the original string's backslashes as per this answer.

Comment: bydefault comoning with \ only with response.

Comment: Please edit the question to add detail about where the response comes from and how you are trying to process it. It seems like it could be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) given your additional comments.